# Use local copy of npm package as another local packages dependency?

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm

sorry if this is a silly question.
I have two cloned react projects written in typescript. `game-react` and `game-renderer`.

in `game-react/package.json` the original developer has:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@gamets/game-renderer": "^1.6.6",
```

I've made local changes to `game-renderer`, how can I use my local changes as the dependency for `game-react` instead, so when I run game-react it has my changes from game-renderer

Comment: You can use npm link https://medium.com/dailyjs/how-to-use-npm-link-7375b6219557